# Why is sessionid the same in session_start in global.ascx.cs?

Tags: asp.net

Every time I start the debugger in VS, I noticed the Session.SessionID in Session_Start(...) in global.ascx.cs is the same. I expected it to be different if a new session is started. Is IIS reusing the sessionid or is there a different explanation?

Comment: When an application is started with session state enabled all request running under the application will be assigned the same session id, unless you do something to preempt this. Once the session times out or the session is abandoned then a new session id will be assigned on the next request for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session ID is tied to the user's cookie, so to force a new session ID every time no matter what you have stored in cookies, then you need to set the `regenerateExpiredSessionId` attribute to `False` in your web.config, like this:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState regenerateExpiredSessionId="False"
        ...
    </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Note: The default value for `regenerateExpiredSessionId` is `True`, see [sessionState element documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: But when the Session_Start fires there's no response coming from the browser at that moment so how would a cookie come in the picture ere?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - response from the browser? Do you mean response from the server? Or do you mean request from the browser?

Comment: I know why I am confused. I thought the Session_Start fires THEN the request comes from the browser. That's why I asked how would the web server know what the sessionid is if the request hasn't come in yet which has the cookie which has the sessionid.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - ah okay, I was starting to wonder if I was not understanding what you were asking. :-)